# Cyclic refinements of abelian towers

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

I was looking through Lang's Algebra and found the following statement,

> Let $G$ be a finite group. An abelian tower of $G$ admits a cyclic refinement.

After some work, I understand the proof, and now I want to show that we cannot drop the hypothesis that $G$ is finite. Its enough to find an infinite abelian group which does not have a cyclic tower. Does anyone know of any such groups? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\large(\mathbb{Q},+){}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$

Also:
$$\large(\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}},+).$$

Comment: The latter example assumes you want a *finite* tower: every element of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ has finite order, so a finite tower of subgroups would necessarily yield a finite group.